# about the lazyload big data size in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I have a set in a mapping as follows:

```
<set name="Persons" cascade="all"  inverse="true" lazy="true">
  <key column="idDepartment" />
  <one-to-many class="Person" />
</set>
```

I would like to load the children in `persons` lazily,
but the persons class has many columns, so the data size is always very big.
If I want to lazily load only one column such as `personid`, how could I go about that?

Answer (score 1):

By default No you can't.

You have two options. Mark all properties that you need rarely as lazy loaded. Then entity will be fetched with subset of properties while others are fetched later. But this can hurt overall perfomance really badly.

Second option is to issue a separate query in order to get some exact columns you want. Nhiberante has projectins for it, or you could use LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using lazy="extra" if your use case is that you only need to load a few of the persons.

You can also question the design of Person - perhaps a smaller Person entity with references to more specific and detailed data is beneficial?

Another option is to simply don't have the Department.Persons collection. I find that I tend to avoid such collections, e.g. where the collection is large and the collection owner doesn't really own the items in the collection.